# The app i developed doesn't open when I click on it

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I developed an android application and today I released a new version of my application. But there is no application icon in my phone. Even if I enter the google play store it doesn't open. How can that be?

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/minik"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/minik"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> ...
   </application>
```

Comment: did you change the package name of your application? and the code you included is pointless.

Comment: LAUNCHER intent-filter is missing

Answer (score 4):

Did you define `launcher activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml` inside `<application>...</application>`?

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

To make your app `launchable`, show `Open` button in Play store and show an icon in phone launcher you should define an activity with intent category `LAUNCHER`

Answer (score 0):

> To launch an activity on clicking App Icon your App must have an activity with `category` **"Launcher"**.
>
> ***Have a look at example below,***

**You hadn't even mentioned your activity name in your** `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Please try to write as below, and your problem will be resolved.

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/minik"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/minik"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"   //mention your activity to be launched
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
 </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing from

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>

            <data
                android:host="www.example.net"
                android:scheme="https"></data>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

to this

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>

            <data
                android:host="www.example.net"
                android:scheme="https"></data>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

solved my problem.